# Display Image in jquery DataTable from Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I m using Jquery Datatables in MVC and want to display Image in it. I know Image can be retrieved from database using below code

```
@{
    string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Content);
    string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
}
```

but no Idea how to do the same using datatable. My Data Table is

```
function GetEmployeesData() {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeesData", "Staff")',
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#employeedatatable').dataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                                    {
                                        'data': 'tbl_StaffImage', "render": function (data) {
                                            return '<img src="tbl_StaffImage" style="height:100px;width:100px;"/>';

                                        }

                                    },

                                    { 'data': 'Name' },

                        ]
                    });


                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing image as `byte[]` in the database then convert it to `base64` string before sending it to the datatable.

and if you are already storing image as `base64` string in the database then your `tbl_StaffImage` data in the datatable should be as below:

```
{
    data: "tbl_StaffImage", name: "tbl_StaffImage",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var imgsrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data; // here data should be in base64 string
        return '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + imgsrc +'" alt="tbl_StaffImage" height="100px" width="100px">';
    }
},
```

Comment: Already done that, the second "up vote" is what I did yesterday. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `columns.render` function to create a custom function. Then use a string to return a correct representation of your image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "" ,render: getImg },
            { title: "" },
            { title: "" }
        ]
    } );
    });

    function getImg(data, type, full, meta) {
       //
       return '<img  src="your image path(imgsrc )" />';
    }
```

Comment: but i m not saving image path. i m saving varbinary image